# Issues on javascript onclick for drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcstsq2v/1/)

May I know, how can I use the onclick event()?

I need, when I click an image or name(Michael-Miami16) or a down arrow, it will drop down list.

In my jsfiddle, my styles are not working. I need like [this](http://s13.postimg.org/522lt1yjr/Untitled_1_copy.png),

Here is javascript:

```
<script>
function ShowHideMenus()
        {
            $('li.userInfo ul').toggleClass("showMenus");
        }
        $('li.userInfo').click(function (event) {
            var tabPageContent = $('.tabPageContent');
            tabPageContent.contents().find('#tblFilterOptions').removeClass("showFilter");
            event.stopPropagation();
            $('li.userInfo ul').toggleClass("showMenus");
        });

        $(document).click(function () {
            $('li.userInfo ul').removeClass("showMenus");
            var tabPageContent = $('.tabPageContent');
            tabPageContent.contents().find('#tblFilterOptions').removeClass("showFilter");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: My page now look like this, http://s11.postimg.org/6z7yunqbn/Untitled_2_copy.png

Comment: Post working css here.

Comment: i posted the whole css code .. but it is not work in jsfiddle link.. sorry..

Comment: You didn't post your css for ul and li for class like: `showMenus`, `userInfo` etc.

Comment: Don't have any other css for showMenus.. i just added showMenus class.. and i posted all css in css.. but its work for me.. but not work in jsfiddle.

Comment: I think, no need styles right?.. We have to know, if click that name, it shows menus and again click that name, it hide the menus..thanks

Comment: I think you need like: http://jsfiddle.net/kcstsq2v/3/ right?

Comment: yes @ketan.. but it shows menus slowly.. i need when i click , it shows quickly.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following jquery and css will solved your issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.weluser').on('click', function(){
        $('.showMenus').slideToggle(100);
    });
})
```

CSS:

```
.showMenus{
    display:none;
}
```

To increase/decrease speed change value inside `slideToggle`.

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kcstsq2v/5/)

Comment: i have one doubt, when i click again somewhere around that name, it didn't hide menus. may i know why?..

Comment: Because `$('.weluser').on('click'` function is written on click of `.weluser`. when you click on `weluser` then only it hide menu.

Comment: so how can i achieve this ? thanks

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/kcstsq2v/6/

Comment: Okay thanks.. in jsfiddle works good.. but in my page, lists are showed by default.. but i used .showMenus { display:none;} but nothing happen,.. thanks

Comment: Check it in developer tool like firebug. if some other may effect.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a lot of unnecessary code to get the navigation to appear. I remove some of it to make it a little more readable. You shouldn't really use onclick methods in the html this is the older way of doing it and since you are using jQuery it is extremely easy to select and element and add the .on function https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.userInfo').on('click', function(){
        $('.showMenus').slideToggle();
    });
})
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcstsq2v/2/)

Comment: But i need show only that name by default, so when i click ,then only it will show.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you not using jQuery library

```
Please Add jQuery library file - 1.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I change your code to this, and It works:

```
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="tdheader fullscreenheader">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tblheader" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:15%;">
            <a class="logo" href="/"><img src="/web5/images/logo.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td style="width:5%;">
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="width:70%;">
            <form action="">
                <ul class="search" class="secure">
<li class="userInfo" onclick = "ShowHideMenus();"><span style="background-image: url('http://s10.postimg.org/oazbazo7p/happy_family_on_the_grass_Medium.jpg');" class="img"></span><span class="weluser">Michael-Miami16</span>
                                    <ul class="showMenus">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="">My Alert Settings</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                              <a href="">My Account Settings</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                             <a href="">Manage Neighborhoods</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="">Add Neighborhood</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="">Log Out</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
        </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
     function ShowHideMenus() {
         $('li.userInfo ul').toggleClass("showMenus");
     }
     $('li.userInfo').click(function (event) {
         var tabPageContent = $('.tabPageContent');
         tabPageContent.contents().find('#tblFilterOptions').removeClass("showFilter");
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
     });

     $(document).click(function () {
         $('li.userInfo ul').removeClass("showMenus");
         var tabPageContent = $('.tabPageContent');
         tabPageContent.contents().find('#tblFilterOptions').removeClass("showFilter");
     });
</script>
<style>
.tdheader ul.secure {
    margin-top: 28px;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li.userInfo {
    position: relative;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    color: #FFF;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #0A315A;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 40px;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li.userInfo span.img {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 35px auto;
    background-position: center top;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li.userInfo span.weluser {
    background: url("http://s21.postimg.org/41n7ygc9f/down_Arrow.png") no-repeat scroll right 12px transparent;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li {
    color: #FFF;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li.userInfo ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #23C2EA;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
    top: 30px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 999999;
    padding: 0px;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    float: left;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    color: #FFF;
}
  .tdheader ul.secure li.liEmail a {
    background: url("img/mail-icon.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 6px transparent;
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 13px;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li a {
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: url("../images/menu-arrows.png") no-repeat scroll right 3px transparent;
    font-family: "myriad_pro";
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li.liEmail a sup {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #F00;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 0px 4px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li.liEmail a {
    line-height: 13px;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li a {
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "myriad_pro";
}
.tdheader ul.secure li.liEmail {
    width: 25px;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    float: left;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    color: #FFF;
}
.tdheader ul.secure li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #0A315A;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 40px;
}

li.userInfo ul {
    display: none;
}
li.userInfo ul.showMenus {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```